Echarts sankey diagram rendering
I'm trying to create a dynamic Sankey diagram with echarts. I have a case where I have a lot of data and my diagram is not really readable as you can see in the image (I have hidden the node names for privacy reasons).

Here are my options :
var option = {
            tooltip: {
                trigger: 'item',
                triggerOn: 'mousemove',
                formatter: function (params) {
                    if (params.dataType === 'edge') {
                        return `${params.data.color}<br>${params.data.source} -->  ${params.data.target} : <b>${formatNumber(params.data.trueValue, formatLocale(lang))}</b>`;
                    }
                    else {
                        return `${params.data.tooltip_text}`;
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {},
            backgroundColor: '{{backgroundColor}}',
            dataZoom: [
                {
                type: 'slider',
                show: true,
                }
            ],
            series: {
                type: 'sankey',
                layout: 'none',
                layoutIterations: 0,
                nodeGap: 8,
                nodeWidth: 20,
                labelLayout: {
                    hideOverlap: true
                },
                emphasis: {
                focus: 'adjacency'
                },
                lineStyle: {
                    color: 'gradient',
                    curveness: 0.4
                },
                label: {
                    show: false,
                    position: 'right',
                    distance: 10,
                },
                data : {{{convertJS data}}},
                links: {{{convertJS links}}},
            }
        };

Here are examples of nodes formatting :
[
  {
    color: 'Inconsistent node',
    name: "Electricity meter TD",
    parents: [
      "Electricity meter 1 D",
      "Electricity meter 2 D",
      "Photovoltaic electricity meter D"
    ],
    tooltip: 'Inconsistent node<br>Sum of datapoints : 2.636<br>Sum of children : 2,599',
    type: 'LT_ELEC',
    itemStyle: { color: '#ffb77f' },
    tooltip_text: 'Inconsistent node<br>Sum of datapoints : 2.636<br>Sum of children : 2,599'
  },
  {
    color: 'Inconsistent node',
    name: "Electricity meter -2 (D)",
    parents: [
      "Electricity meter 1 D"
    ],
    tooltip: 'Inconsistent node<br>Sum of datapoints : 30.69<br>Sum of children : 1,003',
    type: 'LT_ELEC',
    itemStyle: { color: '#ffb77f' },
    tooltip_text: 'Inconsistent node<br>Sum of datapoints : 30.69<br>Sum of children : 1,003'
  },
]

Here are examples of links formatting :
links : [
  {
    color: 'Electrical flow',
    source: "Electricity meter 1 D",
    target: "Electricity meter TD",
    value: 100,
    lineStyle: { color: '#d8db14', opacity: 0.5 },
    trueValue: 0
  },
  {
    color: 'Electrical flow',
    source: "Electricity meter 1 D",
    target: 'Electricity meter -2 (D)',
    value: 190.66666666666669,
    lineStyle: { color: '#d8db14', opacity: 0.5 },
    trueValue: 90.66666666666667
  }
]

You should also know that I sorted my nodes by type.
Does anyone know what I could do to improve the rendering? Because some nodes only have one type of link so they could be placed elsewhere. Here is an example of a change that would make the diagram more readable (I made this example by dragging the nodes).

